# How to custom taxonomy image on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, xcode, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I want add image taxonomy on wordpress

Can you help me in this matter?

http://prntscr.com/v4ghx3

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

you can do that easily with the help of ACF. Please visit the [URL](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/.)

Or you can use the "[Categories Image](https://wordpress.org/plugins/categories-images/)" plugin also